# Wireless card problems

Tags: wireless, drivers, 14.04, internet, broadcom

I'm new to linux so forgive me if this is redundant or unclear. I just finished installing ubuntu (14.04); however, when I try to connect to a wireless network via settings or the top menum I am not seeing a wireless connection option at all. Before installing ubuntu originally, I used the "Try ubuntu without installing" option. I quickly noticed the same problem. Through a little research I was able to find that I could use the "additional drivers" option to install the standard Broadcom driver which would give me back the wireless functionality that I was lacking. After partitioning my hard drive and installing ubuntu, I ran into the same problem as far as no wireless option showing up. I attempted to solve the problem with the previously mentioned method but when I click "Apply Changes" in the "Additional Drivers" tool, it appears as if the driver begins to install and then just stops without completing its install. I've tried this numerous times after restarting and reinstalling but ultimately I always come to the same ends. I tried looking both here and elsewhere on the internet for a possible workaround or solution to my problem and all I am able to find is half-written terminal commands that are nearly illegible to a new-user such as myself.

If anyone has a possible work-around or solution simple enough for a beginner to accomplish, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please do what is in the accepted answer in the link below so we may see the information needed to help diagnose the issue.
<http://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-can-i-do>

Answer (score -1):

After a little more research, I was able to find a set of terminal commands that allowed me to reinstall the driver without incident.